# Laravel validation doesn't seem to work at all

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate the form data as they do in laravel's default authentication. It worked few days ago but now it doesn't work. If user didn't make any mistakes in form and submit it, then it successfully save data in the db. **If user submit an empty form without any data or did some mistake in the form it's not showing the error message. If i add controller function code in a try catch, exception is showing as 'Invalid data'**

view(form)

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('save-service-page-content') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="box-body">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
         <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('file') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
           <label for="image" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Service Image</label>
           <input hidden id="service_image_file" name="file"/>
           <div class="col-sm-10" id="demo-upload">
             <div class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" id="serviceImageUpload">
               <div class="dz-default dz-message">
                  <i class="fa fa-image fa-5x"></i>
                  <h3 class="sbold">Drop an image here to upload</h3>
                  <span>You can also click to open file browser</span>
              </div>
             </div>
             @if ($errors->has('file'))
              <span class="help-block"><strong>The service image is reuired</strong></span>
             @endif
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
           <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
             <textarea rows="8" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Description goes here"></textarea>
             @if ($errors->has('description'))
              <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('description') }}</strong></span>
             @endif
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('description_sin') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
           <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">හැදින්වීම</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
             <textarea rows="8" class="form-control" name="description_sin" placeholder="හැදින්වීම සිංහලෙන්"></textarea>
              <small class="form-text text-muted">හැදින්වීම ඇතුලත් කරන්න. (හැදින්වීම සිංහල බසින් ඇතුලත් කලොත් පමණක් එය ඉංග්‍රීසි බස වෙනුවට සිංහල බසින් දිස්වනු ඇත.)</small>
              @if ($errors->has('description_sin'))
               <span class="help-block"><strong>මෙම හැදින්වමෙහි අක්ෂර සහ ඉලක්කම් පමණක් ඇතුලත් විය යුතුය </strong></span>
              @endif
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <!-- /.box-body -->
     <div class="box-footer clearfix">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Post</button>
     </div>
   </form>
```

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Service_page_content;
use App\Service;
use File;
use Image;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ServiceContent extends Controller
{
  protected function validator(array $data)
 {
   return Validator::make($data, [
      'file' => 'required',
      'description' => 'nullable|alpha_num_spaces_brackets',
      'description_sin' => 'nullable|alpha_num_spaces_brackets',
    ]);
 }


  public function save_page_content(Request $request)
  {
  $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
  $service_page_content = new Service_page_content;
  $service_page_content->description = $request->description;
  $service_page_content->description_sin = $request->description_sin;

  $file = $request->file;
  $image_decode = base64_decode($file);
  $image_data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $file));
  $f = finfo_open();
  $mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $image_data, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $imageName = "service-page-content-".time().'.'.str_replace("image/","",$mime_type);
  $image_resized = Image::make($image_data);
  $image_resized->resize(1170, null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
  });
  $image_resized->save(public_path("uploads/service_page_content_uploads/$imageName"));

  $service_page_content->main_img_url = $imageName;
  $service_page_content->save();
  return redirect()->back()->with('success', ['Data Saved']);
 }
}
```

I don't know if I'm doing it correctly on `return Validator::make($data,......` or `$this->validator($request->all())->validate();`

I have written a custom validation rule that allows alpha numeric, spaces, brackets, '.' and ',' in AppServiceProvider boot function. It also worked few days ago. Now nothing seems to work.

It worked few days ago. Ignore the file upload part it is working perfectly I'm using Dropzone.js for it. May be I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: My little hint would be using Request validations [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation) It keeps your code cleaner aswell.

Comment: "_If user didn't make any mistakes in form and submit it, then it successfully save data in the db_" Doesn't that mean that validation works?

Comment: @kerbholz sorry I forgot add that part. please see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can validate directly on the array without calling the Validator facade.

```
 protected function validator(Request $request)
 {
    return $request->validate([
      'file' => 'required',
      'description' => 'nullable|alpha_num_spaces_brackets',
       'description_sin' => 'nullable|alpha_num_spaces_brackets',
    ]);
 }

public function save(Request $request){
    $this->validator($request);
}
```